# Não consigo autenticar a compra

Tags: php, html

Tipo, quero fazer uma autenticação na hora de finalizar a compra no meu site, pegando nome, email e senha. Sei que tem que fazer um `if` mais não sei como faço, se alguém puder ajudar fico agradecido!!

Código:

```
<div class="contact">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Finalizar Compra</h1>
        <div class="contact-form">
            <div class="col-md-8 contact-grid">
                <form action="mailcl.php" method="post">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="check">  
                             <h1>Revisão</h1>
                             <br />
                             <br />
                             <br />
                            <?php
                                echo 'Nome';
                                echo '<input type="text" name="nome">';
                                echo'Email';
                                echo '<input type="text" name="email" >';
                                echo'Senha';
                                echo '<input type="password" name="senha" >';
                            ?>
                            <div class="send">
                                <input type="submit" value="Comprar">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- //Codigo onde a compra é enviada no email -->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Autenticando usuario</title>
        <style type="text/css"></style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function LoginSucessfully(){
                setTimeout("window.location='index.php'",5000);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
<?php 
    require "PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php";

    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $tabela = $_POST['tabela'];

    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    //$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'marveldc999loja@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = '**********';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    $mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'MarvelDC');
    $mail->addAddress('marveldc999loja@gmail.com');  
    $mail->addAddress($email);    // Add a recipient
    $mail->isHTML(true); // Set email format to HTML

    $mail->Subject =  $email;
    $mail->Body    = $nome;
    $mail->Body    = $tabela;

    $mail->Subject = "Compra efeituada com sucesso!!!";
    $mail->Body  = "<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang='pt-br'>
            <head>
                <meta charset='utf-8'/>
                <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1' name='viewport'>
                <title>Título da Página (Estrutura básica de uma página com HTML 5)</title>
                <link href='css/seu-stylesheet.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
                <script src='scripts/seu-script.js'></script>
            </head>
            <body>
                <font color='black' face='arial'  size='4px'>Olá, $nome<p>
                    <h3>Recebemos o seu pedido!</h3><p> Deposite Nessa Conta o Valor da compra: 4752564814 01 Apos o deposito entraremos em contato para o envio!
                </font>

                $tabela
            </body>
        </html>";

    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    if(!$mail->send()) {
        echo"<center><font color = black>Email ou senha invalidos!!Aguarde um instante para tentar novamente.</font></center>";
            echo "<script>LoginFailed()</script>";
    }else{
        echo"<br /><br />";
        echo"<center><h1><font color='black' face='arial' >O email foi enviado com sucesso!Aguarde um instante que voce sera redirecionado a pagina Home.</font></h1></center>";
        echo"<br /><br />";
        echo"<center><img src='images/carregamento.gif'></center>";
        echo"<script>LoginSucessfully()</script>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Isso tudo é num arquivo só? E que parte vc deseja essa autenticação?

Comment: Quero na parte do  form no primeiro codigo em nome,email e senha

Comment: Você quer verificar se existe um cadastro com nome, email e senha em um banco de dados? Explica melhor isso ai de autenticar a compra

Comment: Sim isso mesmo quero que mostre se o nome , email e senha digitado seja igual ao que esta no banco.